# find: output to a file with a comment

Tags: bash, find

I have a line that will generate the md5sum into a file from files included:

```
find / -type f \( -name "*.pl" -o -name "*.py" \) | md5sum *.pl *.py >> sum.txt
```

The `sum.txt` will output:

```
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  file.pl
60b725f10c9c85c70d97880dfe8191b3  file.py
```

I would need to include the server name after the file name, preferably reading $HOSTNAME as the script will run on different servers, as:

```
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  file.pl  host.one.com
60b725f10c9c85c70d97880dfe8191b3  file.py  host.one.com
```

Comment: That command isn't doing what you expect. Or more specifically that `find` portion is useless. You are throwing away its output and `md5sum` is just running on the `*.pl` and `*.py` files in the current directory. If you want to operate on the output of `find` you need to use `xargs` or `-exec` or similar actually run `md5sum` on the output of the `find` command.

Comment: As to the actual question use `sed` or `awk` or similar to post-process the output file.

Comment: It is actually doing what I need it to do. I have experimented with awk, but don't seem to find a solution.

Comment: You might be getting the output you want but the `find` bit of the command isn't helping you at all. Try without it and you'll see. Also `md5sum *.pl *.py | awk '{print $0, ENVIRON["HOSTNAME"]}' >> sum.txt`.

Comment: Or even just `md5sum *.pl *.py | awk -v ORS=" $HOSTNAME\n" 1`.

Answer (score 1):

The command will search through all `*.pl`and `*.py` files. `find` will exec with `md5sum` command and a hostname will be added to each line. Both commands will generate same output:

```
find / -type f \( -name "*.pl" -o -name "*.py" \) -exec md5sum {} + | awk -v ORS="  $HOSTNAME\n" 1. >> sum.txt

find / -type f -name "*.p[ly]" -exec md5sum {} + |awk -v "h=$HOSTNAME" '{print $0,h}' >> sum.txt
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Comment: The second solution - `"*.p[ly]"` is nice in this case where you are searching for pl and py files. Plus one for that! For a more generic solution you might use `-regex` as I've shown.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be to use find's `-regex` and to use `sed` for appending the hostname:

```
find / -type f -regex '.*\.\(py\|pl\)' -exec md5sum {} + | sed 's/$/ '"$HOSTNAME'/'
```